# replace smiley text with <img> tag

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I'm trying to generate a regex that'll replace an OrderedDictionary's values with the appropriate "`<img src="blah" alt="blah">`" code.

Because it also inputs the `alt=""` text version of the smileys, it matches twice, blowing everything up.

My current attempt is below.

```
foreach (string smiley in Smilies.Keys)
{
    Regex re = new Regex("(?<!(=\"))" + Smilies[smiley] + "(?<!(\"))");
    Trace.WriteLine(re.Replace(msg, @"«img src=""" + path + @"\images\" + Smilies[smiley] + @".gif"" alt=""" + smiley + @"""/»"));
}
```

Smilies are here:

```
        Smilies = new OrderedDictionary();
        Smilies.Add(@"O:)", "angel");
        Smilies.Add(@":-x", "cheekkiss");
        Smilies.Add(@":\", "chin");
        Smilies.Add(@"B)", "cool");
        Smilies.Add(@":~", "crutches");
        Smilies.Add(@"«3", "love");
        Smilies.Add(@"»:(", "mad");
        Smilies.Add(@"):«", "mad");
        Smilies.Add(@":o", "ohmy");
        Smilies.Add(@"@(", "ouch");
        Smilies.Add(@":)", "smile");
        Smilies.Add(@"^_^", "smug");
        Smilies.Add(@"^.^", "smug");
        Smilies.Add(@":+", "therethere");
        Smilies.Add(@":P", "tongue_out");
```

---

EDIT:

This is currently working, for the most part.. Though I think my method of changing the smilies into images is flawed.

`O:) => alt="O:)"` passes the regex's supplied thusfar, yielding a match and replace like
`alt="O:)" => alt="Oalt=":)""`.

Maybe I'm coming at this the wrong way?

```
foreach (string smiley in Smilies.Keys)
{
    string s = Smilies[smiley].ToString();
    string pattern = @"(?<!(=""))" + Regex.Escape(smiley) + @"(?<!(""))";
    string rep = @"«img src=""" + path + @"\images\" + s + @".gif"" alt=""" + smiley + @"""/»";
    Regex re = new Regex(pattern);
    if (re.IsMatch(msg))
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Got a match!");
        string m2 = re.Replace(msg, rep);
        msg = m2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression?

Comment: Because as far as I'm aware, String.Replace won't allow me to set conditionals such as: If match is surrounded by quotes, skip.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working by looping twice through. Once to replace the symbol-based Smileys to their textual counterparts. `:)` = `[smile]` for example.  Then the 2nd time to replace only textual representations into the images, appending the `alt=":)"` tag to the `<img>` code.

While I'm not fond of looping the whole 9 yards twice and doing twice the RegEx's on the input, this is a fairly fool-proof way to do it.

Revised, working code, is below.

```
        foreach (string smiley in Smilies.Keys)
        {
            Regex re = new Regex(Regex.Escape(smiley));
            msg = re.Replace(msg, "[" + Smilies[smiley] + "]");
        }

        foreach (string smiley in Smilies.Keys)
        {
            Regex re = new Regex(@"\[" + Regex.Escape(Smilies[smiley].ToString()) + @"\]");
            msg = re.Replace(msg, @"<img src=""" + Application.StartupPath + @"\images\" + Smilies[smiley] + @".gif"" alt=""" + smiley + @""">");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

this should match and work properly.

```
foreach (string smiley in Smilies.Keys)
{
  Regex re = new Regex("(?<=\")" + Smilies[smiley] + "(?=\")");
  Trace.WriteLine(re.Replace(msg, @"«img src=""" + path + @"\images\" + Smilies[smiley] + @".gif"" alt=""" + smiley + @"""/»"));
}
```

you will have to escape all the special characters in your smiley array where you are making it, like this

```
":)" => "\:\)"
```

Comment: I don't know if it's because the `+ Smilies[smiley] +` part is being interpreted as a literal part of the regex (ie `:)` it thinks is a capture-brace), but it's not replacing anything in the string.
This is indeed the problem, fixing it up yielded this:
`parsing "(?<=")O:)(?=")" - Too many )'s.`

Comment: I actually just used `Regex re = new Regex("(?<=\")" + Regex.Escape(smiley) + "(?=\")");`, now it's simply not matching. `Trace.WriteLine`ing the regex pattern itself is showing it's yielding proper results, it's just not actually matching/replacing anything in `msg`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static string MakeSomeSmilies(string incomingtext)
    {
        var smilies = new OrderedDictionary
        {
            {@"O:)", "angel"},
            {@":-x", "cheekkiss"},
            {@":\", "chin"},
            {@"B)", "cool"},
            {@":~", "crutches"},
            {@"«3", "love"},
            {@"»:(", "mad"},
            {@"):«", "mad"},
            {@":o", "ohmy"},
            {@"@(", "ouch"},
            {@":)", "smile"},
            {@"^_^", "smug"},
            {@"^.^", "smug"},
            {@":+", "therethere"},
            {@":P", "tongue_out"}
        };
        foreach (string m2 in from string smiley in smilies.Keys let re = new Regex(@"(?<!(=""))" + Regex.Escape(smiley) + @"(?<!(""))") where re.IsMatch(incomingtext) select re.Replace(incomingtext, @"«img src=""" + "sd" + @"\images\" + smilies[smiley] + @".gif"" alt=""" + smiley + @"""/»"))
        {
            incomingtext = m2;
        }
        return incomingtext;
    }
```